# debezium-kubernetes not able to build the project

Tags: debezium

I am trying to follow instructions mentioned on below page. However, getting error while building the package.

https://debezium.io/blog/2016/05/31/Debezium-on-Kubernetes/

would someone please let me know how to install Debezium on kubernates

**Error**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:2.2.115:json (json) on project mysql56: Execution json of goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:2.2.115:json failed: A required class was missing while executing io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:2.2.115:json: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:2.2.115
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin/2.2.115/fabric8-maven-plugin-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/kubernetes-api/2.2.115/kubernetes-api-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/openshift-client/1.3.82/openshift-client-1.3.82.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/kubernetes-client/1.3.82/kubernetes-client-1.3.82.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/kubernetes-model/1.0.45/kubernetes-model-1.0.45.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/2.7.2/okhttp-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.6.0/okio-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp/logging-interceptor/2.7.2/logging-interceptor-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp-ws/2.7.2/okhttp-ws-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/github/mifmif/generex/0.0.4/generex-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/dk/brics/automaton/automaton/1.11-8/automaton-1.11-8.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.6.4/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20160212/json-20160212.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.7/dnsjava-2.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/fabric8-devops-connector/2.2.115/fabric8-devops-connector-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/fabric8-devops/2.2.115/fabric8-devops-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/letschat-api/2.2.115/letschat-api-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/taiga-api/2.2.115/taiga-api-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/gitrepo-api/2.2.115/gitrepo-api-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.4/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/gerrit-api/2.2.115/gerrit-api-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/cxf-utils/2.2.115/cxf-utils-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/net/oauth/core/oauth/20100527/oauth-20100527.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.4/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.6.4/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.7.2/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.1.4/cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/3.1.4/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.4/cxf-core-3.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.2.1/xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/3.1.4/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.2.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/javax/el/javax.el-api/2.2.5/javax.el-api-2.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/web/javax.el/2.2.5/javax.el-2.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/fabric8-utils/2.2.115/fabric8-utils-2.2.115.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/jolokia/jolokia-client-java/1.3.3/jolokia-client-java-1.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.3.3/httpclient-osgi-4.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/4.3.0.201604071810-r/org.eclipse.jgit-4.3.0.201604071810-r.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.53/jsch-0.1.53.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.7.9/JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.jsch/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.jsch-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.core/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.core-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.pageant/0.0.9/jsch.agentproxy.pageant-0.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.4/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.11/maven-invoker-2.0.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.1/plexus-utils-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/fki/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : javax.xml.bind.ValidationException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :mysql56
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved the problem with the following changes in the main pom.xml file:

```
  <properties>
    <fabric8.version>2.2.217</fabric8.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <docker.maven.plugin.version>0.15.1</docker.maven.plugin.version>
  </properties>
```

Set `fabric8.version` to the latest 2.2.x and set the default compiler version to Java 1.8.